# How to break up large struct in Swift

Tags: swift, include, project-organization

I have a struct with 120 variables and 70 constants (is translation from FORTRAN physiological model);  I would like to get the initializations and even the declarations out of the struct code because the file will be several thousand lines of code from the algorithms of the model. Here is some code that I thought would work by using a protocol and extension:

```
import Foundation

protocol HasConstants {
    var c1:Double {get set}
    var c2:Double {get set}
}

extension HasConstants {
    func setConstants() -> () {
        var c1 = 3.4
        var c2 = 9.9
    }
}

struct macPuf: HasConstants {
    var c1: Double
    var c2: Double
    setConstants()
}
```

This does not work.  The compiler complains in the extension function that the variables are never used, and in the MacPuf struct it expects a func keyword and brackets, etc. in what it says is an instance method declaration.

Basically I would like to be able to have something like:

```
struct macPuf {
#include InitializeConstants. // for example c1
#include InitializeVariables. // for example var1 .. var45
var1 = var2 * c1
etc.
#include AnotherChunkOfCodeFromExternalFile
var 45 = functionX(var4 + var 6)
etc.
```

I apologize that this is probably a ludicrous question with a ridiculously simple solution. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that protocol even makes sense? Is there more than one viable conformance even possible?

Comment: Without further details is not very clear what are you trying to accomplish here: are you importing data generated in another program into your program written in swift? Are you porting code? Anyway the best approach would be to “divide and conquer” the way your data model is organized. For example a rectangle could be represented as a struct containing another two parameters that are structs, one representing the point of origin and another its dimensions rather then using 4 variables of double values, 2 for the coordinates of the origin and 2 for the width and height.

Comment: Protocols and extensions may not be the right approach.  I am just trying to make a very long file consist of separate files that can be included inline so that I can work on smaller file chunks.

Comment: Show a little if original Fortran code .

Comment: Sorry - I think I have overcomplicated my question.  I have already translated a large FORTRAN program into Swift and it is several thousand lines long.  I am trying to organize it to MVVC model so I can develop an iOS app using the model.  The first 300 lines of code are just initialization and I would like to move it into a different file to shorten.  I am really asking if there is a way to take chunks of code and put them in separate files and then have my main program have a struct that just sequentially includes these files in line.

Comment: @user19414989 Can the 120 variables be split into meaningful "groups"? If so, I think you should just make new structs to contain them, and put those into the parent.

Comment: The reason I was asking about the protocol is because it kind of doubles your property boiler plate (once to define the interface in the protocol, and once to define the storage in the conforming struct). If there's no reasonable other way to conform to the protocol except for your one struct, then you should just remove the protocol and focus on the big struct

Answer (score 0):

I would change constants to enum first of all:

```
enum Constants: Double {
    case c1 = 3.4
    case c2 = 9.9
    // ...
}
```

Second: depending on nature of the variables, your `struct` could include either array or dictionary of the variables, instead of each variable as a property. That way you will only have variables needed for each instance. For example you could make variable name an enum as well to serve as a dictionary key, and variable value will be a dictionary value:

```
enum VariableName {
    case var1
    case var2
    // ...
}

struct MacPuf {

    var fields: [VariableName: Double]
    //...
}
```

In separate file:

```
extension MacPuf {

    func addField(_ name: VariableName, value: Double) {
        fields.update(value for: name)
    }

    func value(for name: VariableName) -> Double? {
        return fields[name]
    }
}
```

So you use it like this:

```
let macPuf = MacPuf()
macPuf.addField(.var1, value: macPuf.value(for: .v2) + Constants.c1.rawValue)
```

And as a side effect your `struct` will now be much shorter. And needless to say all the definitions are in separate files.